# Terminate Script from inside a function?

Tags: python, terminate

I am an absolute beginner to Python and was wondering if there was a way to terminate an entire script from inside a function?

My specific example is that I am using a function to act like the main menu to a text game. I call the function at the beginning of the code, then the actual game coding follows it. I want there to be a way to end the script from the main menu. I've heard:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

However because I use this within a function and there is more for the script to do outside of the function, it carries on with the other parts of the code, rather than immediately stopping. Is there any way to just automatically close out of the script, regardless of where it is? Even if I have to somehow create an error that stops the program, I would be okay with it if there was a way to hide the error from a user.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: could you be more clear as what is your exact problem? [This](http://ideone.com/yAwTNx) seems to work, so in order to understand what's wrong you should post a [minimal example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you show the original code? Because `sys.exit()` should exit the script where ever it occurred.

Comment: `sys.exit` only raises `SystemExit`. If you have a blank `except` somewhere, it may catch it. You should show us the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

sys.exit should be a hard exit from the main thread, however, you can bypass this with a try/except that doesn't specify what it's excepting. A common alternative is to put the main thread inside a try/except with a Keyboard Interrupt and/or system exit.

for example

```
>>> try:
...   # some risky thing
... except:
...   # Dah! catching all exceptions including SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt
...
```

This will prevent a system exit being called in "some risky" from actually exiting (as it's now handled by the except (like an except:/pass)

Better to do

```
>>> def main():
...    try:
...       riskybehavior()
...    except SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt:
...       userExit()
...
>>> def riskybehavior():
...    try:
...       myrisk()
...    except TypeError as te:
...       print str(te)
...
```

Where TypeError is what you expect from myRisk. At the very least,

```
except Exception as e:
```

as SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt are not sub classes of Exception

Answer (score 0):

You could just raise an Exception, and catch it in the level you'd want to return to

for example:

```
class HaltException(Exception):
    pass

def internal_code():
    #some code
    if exit_condition:
        raise HaltException("We decided we want to halt the script")



def main_entry():    
    try:
        #call actual code
        internal_code()
    #Catch exception (to avoid error message)
    except HaltException:
        #And exit cleanly
        return
```

Note- you could use "except KeyboardInterrupt:"  to catch Keyboard interrupts (Ctrl+C on windows)